# My Android project shows empty tabs

Tags: android

I have downloaded code from a site, and it worked good. But when I edited this code according my requirement, it now shows an empty result.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static Context appContext;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    appContext = getApplicationContext();

    ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

    ActionBar.Tab NumbersTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Numbers");
    ActionBar.Tab MessagesTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Messages");

    Fragment NumbersFragment = new AFragment();
    Fragment MessagesFragment = new BFragment();

    NumbersTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(NumbersFragment));
    MessagesTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(MessagesFragment));

    actionbar.addTab(NumbersTab);
    actionbar.addTab(MessagesTab);
}
```

Comment: What does LogCat tell ? What did you change?

Comment: Yes code is running without error but empty shows screen

Comment: This is what happens when you copy/paste code you don't understand. Learn the basics first from the countless training courses available, or you'll  face this situation again in the future...

Comment: @2Dee thanks for advice i have good knoladge of android, but i have not worked on tabs before.

Comment: How can i set pictures in tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

To

```
 if (actionbar.getNavigationMode() == ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS) {
     actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
     actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
 } else {
     actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
     actionbar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
 }
```

Comment: Hope this will work for you but you should check your other java classes NumbersFragment and MessagesFragment also